# How to increase the maximum length of commands entered in the R console

Tags: r

Is there a way of increasing R's [maximum length](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc) of commands entered in the console from ~4095 bytes? (preferably to remove the limit altogether)

I have some very long commands which I need to run but currently cannot

By way of a concrete test if you run this code

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
iris[1:38, ] %>% toJSON(.) %>% dput(.)
```

Then copy/paste the output into the R console to run it (it should work)

However, if you change to `iris[1:39, ]`, copy/paste the output into the R console, it pushes past the byte limit it will hang (with a `+`) which is R (behaviour when the command is too long)

I need a way of extending this limit

Comment: Why do you need to run it via copy/paste? Can't you just save it to a file and `source` it?

Comment: @Gregor good idea, but no, not for what I'm using it for (I'm generating R code to execute in the R interpreter inside of ruby, using `rinruby` gem). Everything else is working great, it's just when the code generated happens to be lengthy, R can't handle it

Comment: This seems a little XY-problemy. I'd recommend editing those details into your question. There might be other work-arounds. [This thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872/2) seems to confirm my suspicion that the way to increase the limit is to re-compile R with a higher limit set. Not sure if that's a viable option for you.

Comment: @Gregor interesting thread indeed. Appreciate it

Comment: Per comment above, perhaps also to write-out the json and read it back in within the interpreter?